# Perl - Split a string containing tuples using regex

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a string containing tuples like below:
`"(-0.345205479452055,1.3543),(-0.26027397260274,1.218),(-0.183561643835616,1.3028)"`

I am trying to split this string to an array containing just the tuples: `[(-0.345205479452055,1.3543),(-0.26027397260274,1.218),(-0.183561643835616,1.3028)]`

I cannot use `Split` function like below since the function also splits up the tuple as well. Is there a regex or some clever way to get the tuples as-is?

`@Tuples = split /,/,$myString;`

Comment: What about `my @array = $str =~ /(\(.*?\))/sg`?

Answer (score 3):

[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can be used for this but requires a slightly more detailed expression.

```
my @str = "(-0.345205479452055,1.3543),(-0.26027397260274,1.218),(-0.183561643835616,1.3028)");
my @arr1 = split(/(?<=\)),(?=\()/, $str);
```

The key here is the use of a zero-width look-behind assertion for checking for a closing paren and the use of a zero-width look-ahead assertion (not exactly necessary here but useful to see) to check for an open paren. Check the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) docs for more info on these.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid `split` altogether then you can use a global match as well.

```
my @arr2 = $str =~ /(\([^)]+\))/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is structured consistently the way you showed, you can use a lookbehind to check and see if the comma comes after a parenthesis.

```
/(?<=\)),/
```

You could also use a negative lookbehind to see if a number is before the comma, and not split there, though that could be confusing to understand.

```
/(?<!\d),/
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no parenthesis inside the tuples, and no parenthesis outside the tuples, you could simply use the following regex:

```
my @array = $str =~ /(\(.*?\))/sg;
```

assuming that there is always a starting parenthesis and a matching end parenthesis for each tuple.

Here

- `*?` is a nongreedy quantifier, see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more information,
- the flag `s` is a regex modifier that lets the `.` also match newlines characters (in case your string contains newlines), see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information,
- the flag `g` stands for global matching and allows the matching operator to match within a string as many times as possible.
  In list context, `g` returns a list of matched groupings, or if there are no groupings, a list of matches to the whole regexp, see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much!..It works.. Yes, there are no paranthesis inside the tuples. If you don't mind, could you explain the code. You have used the capture group (\(.*?\)) to capture the tuple. How does each of the captured scalar get into an array?

Comment: You are welcome, I have updated the question with explanation of how the matches will enter the array.